# Video private links with expiration

Tags: api, vimeo, privacy

On Vimeo (using their API), is it possible to generate private links that automatically expire? If not, what would be a good workflow to approximate this function, based on the API's limitations?

Basically, we would like to provide subscribers to our website limited time access to our videos. We would embed the player links in a private area of the site.

We wouldn't want users to have the ability to copy the link code and keep accessing the videos after their access has expired. Also, in the case of multiple users wanting access to the same video, we wouldn't want any updates to the privacy settings of a video to interfere with previous user access granted (that has not yet expired).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to do exactly the same thing, either with Vimeo or some other VOD service.

Comment: To begin with, they could easily download the video while subscribed to it using an extension like Vimeo Private Downloader for Chrome... Do you have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The Vimeo API can only toggle a video's [privacy settings](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview), the API cannot grant playback to a viewer outside of the privacy settings available.

For example, the API can be used to [set a video](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos?version=3.4#edit_video) as password-protected and set the video's password, however the API cannot be used to authenticate and bypass password protection and allow playback.

Comment: How about we create our custom api endpoint to get video redirect to vimeo, but on every it would change the video password using vimeo api. this way every call will expire the password and only your api endpoint would know if the user should have access to the current one.

Comment: @NickKovalsky I think that would be possible, but it would require a lot of work with frequent changing of your video's password, not to mention you'd have to generate a new password every time. Doing a PATCH or POST on every page load, I feel like you'd be more likely to run into timeout or rate limit issue also.

Answer (score 0):

You could deal with this by providing a redirect from your own site and have the redirect expire. That would provide the functionality you’re looking for, but it’s also very easy to circumvent. It depends how strict/hard you want to make the expiry.